# How to avoid rerendering when using react redux forms?

Tags: forms, performance, reactjs, redux, rendering

I am using "react-redux-form". 
But I noticed whole FORM which is little bit bigger is rerendered everytime I call
dispatch(action...) or onChange(val) in custom Control component.

Whole form re-rendering is causing massive lags as it is rerendering totally unecessary components.

What can I do to avoid this re-rendering and totally slowing whole page while user is typing..?

I should maybe implement custom shouldComponentUpdate(), but I do not know what should be inside?

Other solution is to only re-render onBlur but this is not possible ,because I am doing error checking while user types.

Should not it be feature in "react-redux-forms" to only rerender what really changed? Not whole Form?

Comment: Would you mind posting your form code? My experience with react-redux-form is that it can render things like validations faster than users can type (even for large forms), but I've run into laggy form performance if I have fields that have cyclical dependencies in the form render, especially with validation definitions. The settings of the form would help a lot to debug!

Comment: Redux always triggers a re-render on dispatch in my experience. It's not been a problem in the applications I've worked on, unless there's a lot of processing going on in render().